# Python Pandas Update Value Based on Index using .iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame

```
a=pd.DataFrame([[1,1,9],[2,1,9],[3,2,9],[4,2,9]],columns=['a','b','c'])

   a  b  c
0  1  1  9
1  2  1  9
2  3  2  9
3  4  2  9
```

if I run

```
a['c'].iloc[0]=100
```

it works and I get

```
   a  b    c
0  1  1  100
1  2  1    9
2  3  2    9
3  4  2    9
```

But if I want to update the first observation of group b==2 by running

```
a['c'][a['b']==2].iloc[0]=100
```

It doesn't do what I want it do. I still get the same dataframe.

```
   a  b    c
0  1  1  100
1  2  1    9
2  3  2    9
3  4  2    9
```

I wonder why? and what's a possible solution for this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should using `.loc` like this, chian with `.iloc` and `.loc` sometime will cause the [issue](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

> ```
>  Whether a copy or a reference is returned for a setting operation, may depend on the context. This is sometimes called chained> assignment and should be avoided
> ```

```
a.loc[a.index[a.b==2][0],'c']=10000
a
Out[761]: 
   a  b      c
0  1  1      9
1  2  1      9
2  3  2  10000
3  4  2      9
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on BENY's answer, I was interested in changing a set of values based on a calculation.

The code below uses a set of indexes on the left and right sides of the assignment:

```
a=pd.DataFrame([[1,1,9],[2,1,9],[3,2,9],[4,2,9]],columns=['a','b','c'])
print(a)
a.loc[a.index[a.b==2],'c']=10000 + a.loc[a.index[a.b==2],'a']
print(a)

# prints:

   a  b  c
0  1  1  9
1  2  1  9
2  3  2  9
3  4  2  9
   a  b      c
0  1  1      9
1  2  1      9
2  3  2  10003
3  4  2  10004
```

and

```
a=pd.DataFrame([[1,1,9],[2,1,9],[3,2,9],[4,2,9]],columns=['a','b','c'])
print(a)
a.loc[a.index[a.b==2],'c']=10000 + a.loc[a.index[a.b==2],'a']
print(a)

indices = a.index[a.index%2==1]
print(indices)

a.loc[indices,'c'] = a.loc[indices,'c']/2
print(a)
```

prints

```
  a  b  c
0  1  1  9
1  2  1  9
2  3  2  9
3  4  2  9
   a  b      c
0  1  1      9
1  2  1      9
2  3  2  10003
3  4  2  10004


a   b   c
0   1   1   9.0
1   2   1   4.5
2   3   2   10003.0
3   4   2   5002.0
```

This uses the `.values` of the indices to swap data from alternate rows:

```
a=pd.DataFrame([[1,1,9],[2,1,9],[3,2,9],[4,2,9]],columns=['a','b','c'])
print("original\n",a)
a.loc[a.index[a.b==2],'c']=10000 + a.loc[a.index[a.b==2],'a']
print("\naugmented:\n",a)

indicesOdd = a.index[a.index%2==1]
indicesEven = a.index[a.index%2==0]
print(indicesOdd, indicesEven)

a.loc[indicesOdd,'d'] = -a.loc[indicesEven,'c'].values
a.loc[indicesEven,'d'] = a.loc[indicesOdd,'c'].values
print("\nswapped and negated:\n",a)

# prints:

original
    a  b  c
0  1  1  9
1  2  1  9
2  3  2  9
3  4  2  9

augmented:
    a  b      c
0  1  1      9
1  2  1      9
2  3  2  10003
3  4  2  10004
Index([1, 3], dtype='int64') Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')

swapped and negated:
    a  b      c        d
0  1  1      9      9.0
1  2  1      9     -9.0
2  3  2  10003  10004.0
3  4  2  10004 -10003.0
```